# Can we have two Indexer in One Fredhopper Instance?

Tags: fredhopper

How can we create two indexer one for Staging one for Live on same Fredhopper instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple *query* servers based on the same indexer, but multiple indexers on the same *instance* would make it impossible to know what content to serve. It would be like wanting to run two different Content Managers on the same port and machine.

However, you can have multiple *instances* on the same Fredhopper *installation* (machine) -- which is what you would normally use for the Live/Staging split. If you need to scale out, you could put them on two separate machines later.

As for how you create them, this is [covered in the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-14B27D8D-388D-4021-AA97-26416AA55C94). Essentially just repeat the process that you did for the first instance (staging) to create a second instance (live).

Comment: So What I understood is, Using different presets We should install two different Instance of fredhopper on same machine. What I was thinking was to create two separate indexer.  As per you two Index on same fredhopper instance will make fredhopper to not to server content properly then in that case, my question are 1.) Then why there is option available to create multiple indexer instance. 2) For me Query Servers are used to return content, Why Indexes is coming in picture for returning data.

Comment: I feel like we're not using the same terms and that might be causing confusion. FAS is an installation and it can have multiple instances. Each will get their own port (8180, 9180, etc.) and serve their own content, separate from each other. Each instance can have an indexer (which contains the content) and one or more query servers (that serve the content to the website). So you don't need to install more Fredhoppers to have both Live and Staging on the same machine -- but you do need to create them as separate *instances* on the same Fredhopper.

Comment: Ohk, What I will do, I will try to see behavior of Creating two Indexer on same Fredhopper instance using separate preset. Will update my finding here. Anyways Thanks Peter..

Comment: Using different presets in topology.txt will indeed result in separate instances on different ports, so that is what I am advocating.